# Concentric Rectangles with Grid

Tags: wpf

I am completely new to WPF, so please be gentle.  :)  I have a 4x4 grid.  Within each cell, I want to have concentric rectangles that frame the cell and then place widgets within them.  The outer rectangle is to fill the cell.  The inner rectangles are then to be within the boundaries of the outer rectangles, etc.  I am able to place the first rectangle successfully.  However, I am having a devil of a time placing the inner rectangles.  My gut says this should be doable without code-behind.

I've tried a canvas within a canvas, not to mention various permutations and combinations.

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
            <Canvas>
                <Rectangle Canvas.Left="0" Stroke="Gray" Canvas.Top="0" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" StrokeThickness="20" x:Name="r0c0"
                           Stretch="Fill" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" 
                           Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>

                <Rectangle Canvas.Left="15" Stroke="Blue" Canvas.Top="15" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" StrokeThickness="10"
                           Stretch="Fill" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=r0c0}" 
                           Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=r0c0}"/>
            </Canvas>
       </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Canvas and rectangle was overdoing it.  Borders were the route to go.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
   <Border BorderThickness="20" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="10" 
      Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
   <Border BorderThickness="10" BorderBrush="Blue" CornerRadius="10" 
      Margin="15,15,15,15"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just a syntax tip.  If your Margin values are all the same like you have here, you can shorten them to Margin="0"  and Margin="15"  Still works the same

Comment: Thanx for that!  A colleague once said, "when you're born, God assigns you a certain number of keystrokes.  When you use them up, you die."  Now, I'm gonna live to be 100!  :)